# Is the Air Hike skill required for any of the collectables?

Tags: devil-may-cry-5

The description for the Air Hike skill suggests you can reach higher locations. So is this skill required for any of the collectables/secrets, or can they all be obtained without it?

If it is required, does this apply to all characters, or a specific one/two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having now obtained all collectables I can confirm that the Air Hike skill is not required for any of them.

It does make one of the secret missions a bit easier to complete, but it isn't required.

Comment: gerbera is a new air hike :D